# Brother network printer config for Synology DiskStation AirPrint server

Tags: networking, nas, synology, google-cloud-print

Synology DiskStation's DSM 5+ NAS OS includes Apple AirPrint and Google CloudPrint server services. However, it doesn't include drivers for my specific printer, a Brother DCP-7065DN. Do I need to manually add the Linux drivers to DSM somehow, or are there settings that will allow this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the closest available printer driver (`Brother DCP-8045D`) and the `PCL_P1` printer queue (instead of BINARY_P1), and *some* AirPrint jobs will go through.

[image]

This works for printing *some* types of documents but not others. Images and photos do not seem to be directly printable (Photos or MMS attachments) -- the job is sent, but the printer displays 'Receiving Data' indefinitely, until the job is cancelled (Alternatively, images *can* be printed using the Brother iPrint&Scan app). Most other documents, even documents that contain images (e-mail), are AirPrint-able.